# Ubuntu 14.04 Display UNCLAIMED

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, ati

My computer's graphics seem to be having issues. Here is the output of `sudo lshw -c display` before the problem:

```
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: RV710 [Radeon HD 4350/4550]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:46 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:feae0000-feaeffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:feac0000-feadffff
```

And after the problem:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: RV710 [Radeon HD 4350/4550]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:feae0000-feaeffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:feac0000-feadffff
```

Under **System Settings** > **Graphics**, it no longer shows "Gallium 0.4 on AMD R710" and it now shows "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 128 bits)".

The screen is sized really bad and the startup is weird.

If theres any info i can add please lmk

Comment: Did you try to install any drivers? If you did, this is the problem.

Comment: I believe I have, how can I uninstall them?

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMD proprietary drivers do not support this old adapter.

You need to remove them. The right way to remove the drivers depends on the way you installed them.

If you installed AMD drivers from a deb package, Ubuntu repositories or a PPA, you can un-install the drivers by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'fglrx.*'
```

in terminal.

Comment: OMG YOUVE FIXED IT, I LOVE YOU SO MUCH, YOU ARE MY NEW FAVORITE PERSON